# Flagging overlapping datetime ranges

Tags: python, datetime

I have a tuple in the following format:

```
tup = [('15MAR18 103000', '15MAR18 103758'), ('15MAR18 103555', '15MAR18 121308')] etc...
```

in the form `tup = [(a,b), (a,b)]` where `a = start_end` and `b = end_time`

I am trying to flag if the dates between the starts and ends clash with any other start and end datetimes...

I need to then Flag whether it does or doesn't clash and insert into each nested tuple 'Y/N'

I'm not exactly how the logic needs to be structured on this.

I think I would need to find if any start time is less than the previous end time.

```
for x in range(0, len(tup)):
    if tup[x-1][0] > tup[x][1]
     .....
```

Comment: Have you some code to show your latest attempt?

Comment: Think of how you would do it by hand or in your head. Can you describe it? Then write a program and show us.

Comment: Besides, I think you should think of it as a list of tuples, not nested. "Nested" sounds like tuples within tuples.

Answer (score 0):

This is the brute-force method. There is scope for optimization.

```
from datetime import datetime

nested_tup = [('15MAR18 103000', '15MAR18 103758'),
              ('15MAR18 103555', '15MAR18 121308'),
              ('16MAR18 103555', '16MAR18 121308')]

def check_overlap(x, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if (i[0] < x[0] < i[1]) or (i[0] < x[1] < i[1]):
            return True
    else:
        return False

lst = [tuple(datetime.strptime(i, '%d%b%y %H%M%S') for i in x) for x in nested_tup]

res = [check_overlap(x, lst) for x in lst]

nested_tup = [i + (j,) for i, j in zip(nested_tup, res)]

# [('15MAR18 103000', '15MAR18 103758', True),
#  ('15MAR18 103555', '15MAR18 121308', True),
#  ('16MAR18 103555', '16MAR18 121308', False)]
```